# How to create database on restore

Tags: postgresql

I want pg_restore to create database before restore using Postgres 12 on Debian 10

I tried

```
PG_COLOR=auto
PGHOST=localhost
PGPASSWORD=mypass
PGUSER=postgres
export PGHOST  PGPASSWORD PG_COLOR PGUSER
pg_restore --clean --create --if-exists --dbname=mydb  --jobs=4 --verbose "mydb.backup"
```

but got error

> pg_restore: connecting to database for restore pg_restore: error:
>   connection to database "mydb" failed: FATAL:  database "mydb" does not
>   exist

How to create database before restore ?

using Postgres 12 on Debian 10

Comment: uhm ... by running `createdb` before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pg_restore [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) explains this error:

> -C
>   --create
>
> Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting to
>   it.
>
> With --create, pg_restore also restores the database's comment if any, and any configuration variable settings that are specific to this
>   database, that is, any ALTER DATABASE ... SET ... and ALTER ROLE ...
>   IN DATABASE ... SET ... commands that mention this database. Access
>   privileges for the database itself are also restored, unless --no-acl
>   is specified.
>
> When this option is used, **the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands**. All
>   data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive.

You must pass a pre-existing database to `-d` for instance with `-d postgres`
 or `-d template1`. Also note that your backup should contain the `CREATE DATABASE` command, whose presence depends on the arguments used with `pg_dump`.